# UISwipeGestureRecognizer with SpriteKit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios8, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am creating a game in swift that involves making words out of letters. The letters, which are individual SKSpriteNodes, sit on a "shelf" which is a SKSpriteNode. To remove the letters from the "shelf", I am trying to introduce swiping up. Unfortunately I am having issues with the swipe being picked up by the letters. The shelf seems to be absorbing it, or sometimes even the SKScene. I have disabled the user interaction on the shelf node.

This is my setup:

```
swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("move:"))
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

I add the swipeRecognizer to the view, then in the move method, I have the following:

```
func move(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){        
    if(swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended && swipe.numberOfTouches() == 1){

        var touchLocation = swipe.locationInView(swipe.view)
        touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)            
        var sprite = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

        if sprite is Letter{
            let letter = sprite as Letter
            if(gameManager.letterOnShelf(letter)){
                gameManager.letterFlicked(letter)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only sometimes to it recognize the sprite as a letter, 80% of the time the sprite is the shelf and I can't figure out what the correct way to work it is.....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers all!!

Comment: Would it be possible to post a picture of the layout? If not, are the letters below/above the board and how far away are they?

Comment: the zPositions are: shelf.zPosition = 0 letter.zPosition = 3. For all letters added to the screen. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

1. Using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with `minimumPressDuration` set to 0.
2. When the gesture is at the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state, see if the sprite your touch is over is a `Letter` and save a reference to that tile.
3. In the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state, you should be able to see what location your gesture ended (or perhaps the trajectory, etc) and then move the tile you stored a reference to from earlier.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good way to do it. It doesn't seem to meet the condition if(swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) ever though. Only registers UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended. I set a break point and all the only time move: is called is for the ended state. <UISwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x156a5950; state = Ended; view = <SKView 0x155b9080>; target= <(action=move:, target=<blocks.GameScene 0x15697c50>)>; direction = up>

Comment: I have to try tweak my code a little because I am already using {touchesBegan touchesMoved touchesEnded}. Using the {UILongPressGestureRecognizer} seems to have over hauled them

Comment: OK so I have come back to this guy and found a solution. Slightly different to yours but using some of the same principals. I created an SKSpriteNode called letterSwiped. When touchesBegan happens, I save the letter, which is of type Letter. Then if the swipeGesture method is called, I check the type of the letterSwiped variable. i.e. if its of type Letter, action happens, if its of type SKSpriteNode, do nothing.

Comment: That sounds pretty good! I would just be careful about swiping on a cell you didn't mean to. Maybe you should invalidate the cell selection after a period of time or something. But anyway, glad you found something that worked!